# How to append two different div while print pdf datatable?

Tags: jquery, printing, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

how to append two different div while print the datatable as PDF.
i want to show first div above the datatable and another div after the datatable.

Now only the datatable is coming on the print page.

```
      <div id="beforedatatable" style="margin:0px;">
      <br/>
        <div style="">
            <h4 style="text-align:center;margin: 0; line-height: 1.428571;" class="modal-title">sample title</h4>
            <h5 style="text-align:center;margin: 0; line-height: 1.428571;" class="modal-title">sample title123</h5>
      <div class="prtnrow">
           <div class="prtncolumn">
              <p><span style="text-transform: uppercase;" class="prnt_contractname">sample title4<span></p>
              <p><span class="prnt_branchname">sample title5<span></p>
              <p><span class="prnt_branchcity">sample title46<span></p>
              <br>
              <p><span class="prnt_contractsubject">Subject: <span></p>
              <p><span class="">Dear sir,<span></p>
              <p><span class="prnt_contractreference">with reference to the-----<span></p>

           </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        </div>




    <div id="afterdatatable" style="margin:0px;">
      <br/>
        <div style="">
   <div class="prtnrow">
               <div class="prtncolumn">
                  <p><span class="prntcusterms"><span>dsjkfldfsdfsdjkfgs</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </table>
      <!-- end print content -->
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the code for the datatable with PRINT button.When click the print button i need to append the two different div from above the datatable and after the datatable.

```
    $('.jobshepest').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {                

        $('.examplejobshecdule').DataTable({
                destroy: true,
                searching: false,
                responsive: true,

        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
        { title: "Premises" },
        { title: "Type of treatment" },
        { title: "Frequency" },
        { title: "Date" },
        {title: "Time"}],
        order: [[2, "asc"]],
        columnDefs: [
        { width: "23%", targets: 3 }
    ],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [{
          extend: 'pdf',
          className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-file printpdfschedule',
          title: 'Title test',
          filename: 'Job-schedule',
          //messageTop: 'This print was produced using the Print button for DataTables',
        customize: function (doc) {
                    // Set the font size fot the entire document
                    doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 10;
                    // Set the fontsize for the table header
                    doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 10;
                        doc['footer']=(function(page, pages) {
                        return {
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    alignment: 'center',
                                    text: ['sample footer text']
                                },
                            ],
                            margin: 20
                        }
                    });
            }
        }]
      });


});
```